# npm ERR! publish You cannot publish over the previously published

Tags: npm, package.json

> npm ERR! publish Failed PUT 403
>   npm ERR! code E403
>   npm ERR! You cannot publish over the previously published versions: 1.1.1. :

I cannot seem to publish even after using `npm version patch`.

Here is what my steps:

`npm version patch`, this updates my package.json to a new version, then I use `npm publish`, but I get this error every time, even though I get an email saying it is successful, and the npm package does seem to be updated as well.

Here is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "react-mapbox-helper",
    "version": "1.1.1",
    "description": "A mapbox wrapper for displaying point features with hover",
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc",
        "patch": "npm version patch",
        "minor": "npm version minor",
        "major": "npm version major",
        "publish": "npm publish"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/leogoesger/react-mapbox-helper"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "Leo Qiu <leoq91@gmail.com>",
    "license": "MIT",
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/leogoesger/react-mapbox-helper/issues"
    },
    "homepage": "https://github.com/leogoesger/react-mapbox-helper",
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "^2.9.2",
        "@types/mapbox-gl": "^0.45.2",
        "@types/react": "^16.4.6"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "mapbox-gl": "^0.47.0-beta.1",
        "react": "^16.4.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Jut ran into the same problem; I realised that I had already published (from another workstation) a version of my package that was `>=` the version that I was trying to publish. Maybe that works for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

Hi You already publish this version!
so increment that version for example if it (1.1.1) to(1.1.2)
then `run npm i`